# ¿Utilizar evento onkeyup para actualizar input?

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña calculadora para las comisiones de paypal, por los momentos funciona, pero me gustaría hacerle un cambio que hasta los momentos no he logrado acertar. Resulta que quiero que en lugar de tener que dar click en el botón calcular, para obtener la comisión a pagar. Quiero que esta se actualice automáticamente en el input correspondiente al ir tecleando las cantidades.

He probado añadir un event listener al input donde se recibe la cantidad, pero aparentemente no funciona de esa forma, lo que he hecho es algo como esto:

```
cantidadARecibir = document.getElementById('cantidadARecibir');
cantidadARecibir.addEventListener('onkeyup', function () {
    //Aquí el código de la calculadora
})
```

El código que tengo desarrollado es el siguiente:

Javascript

```
botonCalcular = document.getElementById('calcular'); 
botonCalcular.addEventListener('click', function () {
    cantidadARecibir = document.getElementById('cantidadARecibir');
    cantidadARecibir = Number(cantidadARecibir.value) || 0;

    tasaPorcentaje = document.getElementById('tasaPorcentaje');
    tasaPorcentaje = Number(tasaPorcentaje.value) || 5.4;

    if (cantidadARecibir > 0) {
        cantidadAEnviar = document.getElementById('cantidadAEnviar');
        cantidadAEnviar.className = 'exitoso';         
        //cantidadAEnviar.value = (((cantidadARecibir * (tasaPorcentaje/100)) + 0.3) + cantidadARecibir);         
        cantidadAEnviar.value = ((cantidadARecibir + 0.3) * 100 / (100 - tasaPorcentaje)).toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculadora de comisión paypal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedorImportante">
            <header>
                <h1>Calculadora de comisiones <span class="logo pay">Pay</span><span class="logo pal">pal</span></h1>
            </header>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" id="cantidadARecibir" placeholder="Para recibir">
                <input type="text" id="tasaPorcentaje" placeholder="Con una tasa de 5.4%">                         
                <input type="text" id="cantidadAEnviar" placeholder="Tendrían que enviarle" readonly>                
            </form>
            <div class="contenedorBotones">
                <button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
                <button id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
            </div>      
        <div class="nota">
            <p>Dejando vacía la caja de "tasa", se toma por defecto el valor 5.4%</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <footer>       
    <p class="copy">PayPal, es una empresa estadounidense que opera en casi todo el mundo un sistema de pagos en línea que soporta transferencias de dinero entre usuarios y sirve como una alternativa electrónica a los métodos de pago tradicionales como cheques y giros postales.
        <br><br>
        Este sitio web <b>no tiene ninguna relación con la web oficial de PayPal</b> (wwww.paypal.com), sólo tiene como finalidad ser una herramienta para poder calcular las comisiones de envios y así recibir o enviar los montos correctos.</p>
    <br><br>
        <p>Desarrollado por: <a class="enlace" href="http://pedrofumero.com/">Pedro Fumero</a><br><a href="https://twitter.com/PedroFumero">Twitter</a> - <a href="https://github.com/PedroFumero">Github</a></p>
    </footer>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rubén ya he añadido el código HTML completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De hecho lo estás haciendo de forma correcta, el único problema que tienes es en el nombre del evento. Es `keyup` en lugar de `onkeyup`.

Aquí la documentacion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup

Y aquí tu código funcionando:

```js
botonCalcular = document.getElementById('calcular');
botonCalcular.addEventListener('click', function() {
  doCalc();
});
cantidadARecibir = document.getElementById('cantidadARecibir');
cantidadARecibir.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  doCalc();
})


var doCalc = function() {
  cantidadARecibir = document.getElementById('cantidadARecibir');
  cantidadARecibir = Number(cantidadARecibir.value) || 0;

  tasaPorcentaje = document.getElementById('tasaPorcentaje');
  tasaPorcentaje = Number(tasaPorcentaje.value) || 5.4;

  if (cantidadARecibir > 0) {
    cantidadAEnviar = document.getElementById('cantidadAEnviar');
    cantidadAEnviar.className = 'exitoso';
    //cantidadAEnviar.value = (((cantidadARecibir * (tasaPorcentaje/100)) + 0.3) + cantidadARecibir);         
    cantidadAEnviar.value = ((cantidadARecibir + 0.3) * 100 / (100 - tasaPorcentaje)).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contenedor">
  <div class="contenedorImportante">
    <header>
      <h1>Calculadora de comisiones <span class="logo pay">Pay</span><span class="logo pal">pal</span></h1>
    </header>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" id="cantidadARecibir" placeholder="Para recibir">
      <input type="text" id="tasaPorcentaje" placeholder="Con una tasa de 5.4%">
      <input type="text" id="cantidadAEnviar" placeholder="Tendrían que enviarle" readonly>
    </form>
    <div class="contenedorBotones">
      <button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
      <button id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="nota">
      <p>Dejando vacía la caja de "tasa", se toma por defecto el valor 5.4%</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="copy">PayPal, es una empresa estadounidense que opera en casi todo el mundo un sistema de pagos en línea que soporta transferencias de dinero entre usuarios y sirve como una alternativa electrónica a los métodos de pago tradicionales como cheques y giros
      postales.
      <br><br> Este sitio web <b>no tiene ninguna relación con la web oficial de PayPal</b> (wwww.paypal.com), sólo tiene como finalidad ser una herramienta para poder calcular las comisiones de envios y así recibir o enviar los montos correctos.</p>
    <br><br>
    <p>Desarrollado por: <a class="enlace" href="http://pedrofumero.com/">Pedro Fumero</a><br><a href="https://twitter.com/PedroFumero">Twitter</a> - <a href="https://github.com/PedroFumero">Github</a></p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Nache, todavía estoy batallando por aprender las palabras reservadas del lenguaje, con razón no me funcionaba de ninguna manera,